# Resizing userControls in newly initiated TabPage

Tags: vb.net, browser, user-controls, tabcontrol, tabpage

When a new TabPage is added in my TabControls, I would like it to autosize to Form1's current height/width. I can do this on Form Load. However, when I add a new tab then resize the window, it does nothing. Thanks for any helpful input.

Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1

```
'The Global Variables
Dim theControls As New theControls


Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'For Auto Sizing theControls to Form1
    TabPage1.Controls.Add(theControls)

    theControls.theBrowser.Navigate("http://google.com")
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_SizeChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.SizeChanged


    'For Auto Sizing theControls to Form1

    Me.TabControl1.Width = Me.Width - 20
    Me.TabControl1.Height = Me.Height
    theControls.Width = Me.TabControl1.Width - 20
    theControls.Height = Me.TabControl1.Height - 20



End Sub

Private Sub TabControl1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TabControl1.Click

    'Add new tab with the same controls.
    Dim theNewTab As New TabPage
    Dim theOtherControls As New theControls
    Dim theTabCounter As Integer = TabControl1.TabPages.Count


    Dim theSelectedTab As String = TabControl1.SelectedTab.Text

    If theSelectedTab = "+" Then
        TabControl1.TabPages.Insert(theTabCounter - 1, theNewTab)
        theNewTab.Controls.Add(theOtherControls)

        theControls.theBrowser.Navigate("http://google.com")
        theOtherControls.theBrowser.Navigate("http://google.com")
        TabControl1.SelectTab(theTabCounter - 1)
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

The tabPageCounter variable can be ignore. I started to think a For Each loop would be needed but I think there's an easier way. From what I have found on the web, I have gotten to this Dock function but I guess I'm not exactly clear on how to use it...

Answer (score 0):

Do it in Form_sizechanged event ..

```
Private Sub Form1_SizeChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.SizeChanged
    Me.TabControl1.Width = Me.Width - 20
    myUserControl.Width = Me.TabControl1.Width -20
End Sub
```

Comment: Whenever I try and do it that way, I get an error saying "Expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment."

Comment: Negative. Error stating "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference."


    Private Sub TabControl1_SizeChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TabControl1.SizeChanged
        Form.AutoSize = True
        Me.Size.Width = TabControl1.Size.Width + 20
    End Sub

Comment: That's perfect. However it's still not resizing the newly added tab page. It still stay in a static state (Smaller than Form 1 itself). (Code Updated)

Comment: So I have Form1 with TabControls1. On top of that I have UserControls which I want resized to fit the dimensions of whatever Form1 is sized to. I've gotta be doing something stupid...this sounds like it should be relatively straight forward... **At a high level, I'm trying to make a Browser that has Tabs. When the browser is resized, I want all the controls in UserControls to autosize to the Window.** My UserControls hold things like the Address Bar, Browser Window...

Comment: That didn't work either. It just stayed in the same size (smaller than Form1 itself).

Comment: Sorry. Should be a little bit more descriptive...the way I have this set up is in Form1, I just have nothing but a TabControl. Outside of that, I have usercontrols (fields and buttons) and when Form1 loads, I add the usercontrols to the TabPage. At the current state, when I resize Form1, none of the UserControls get resized. They just stay static and the static size is smaller than the TabControls